# When you remove a device from find my iPhone, does it's automatically restore?

Tags: find-my-iphone

I dropped my iPhone and the screen is completely unusable. I got a deductable for a new one and the instructions said to turn off find my iPhone for my original device, so I did from my computer. However, the next instructions were to restore it to factory settings, but since I turned off find my iPhone I can't restore it now. Help?

Comment: Why would you want to restore the broken phone? You should have backed up the old phone to iTunes, Erased from Find my iPhone, then removed it from the account. Then when you plug your new phone to iTunes, one option would be Restore. It will set up your new phone just like your old one.

Comment: Do you means Reset or erase instead of "restore"?

Answer (score 1):

You can still restore an iOS device even if it has a broken screen. Connect it to iTunes over USB and click Restore iPhone. Because you have disabled Find my iPhone, iTunes will let you restore the device.